# C# Appending string to encrypted text file adds extra unwanted characters at start

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I am trying to append the strings to the encrypted text file as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data). But when I do this second time the extra unwanted characters are adding at the start.

First time (when text file is empty, everything is ok)-
[image]

But when I append the text file again the extra unwanted characters are appearing at the start.-
[image]

My code for encryption and decryption is-

Encyption code-

```
void Encrypt()
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new(FilePath, FileMode.Append);
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        byte[] key =
        {
            0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
            0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16
        };
        aes.Key = key;
        byte[] iv = aes.IV;
        fileStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(fileStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        StreamWriter encryptWriter = new(cryptoStream);

        encryptWriter.Write($"RideTitle: {_trakingStartDateTime + _trakingEndDateTime}");
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");
        encryptWriter.Write($"UserNote: -");
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");
        encryptWriter.Write($"MaxSpeed: {MaxSpeed}");
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");
        encryptWriter.Write($"AvgSpeed: {AvgSpeed}");
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");
        encryptWriter.Write($"TotalDistance: {TotalDistance}");
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");
        encryptWriter.Write($"Steps: {TotalSteps}");
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");
        encryptWriter.Write($"TotalTime: {_timeElaspsedString_TwentyFourHr}");
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");

        encryptWriter.Write("SpeedPoints: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < SpeedPointList.Count; i++)
        {
            encryptWriter.Write($"{SpeedPointList[i]},");
        }
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");

        encryptWriter.Write("TimeStampPoints: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < timestampListStings.Count; i++)
        {
            encryptWriter.Write($"{timestampListStings[i]},");
        }
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");

        encryptWriter.Write("LocationPoints: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < LocationListForFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            encryptWriter.Write($"{LocationListForFiles[i].Latitude}_{LocationListForFiles[i].Longitude},");
        }
        encryptWriter.Write("\n");

        encryptWriter.Close();
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

Decryption code-

```
async Task<List<String>> Decrypt()
    {
        if(File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
             FileStream fileStream = new(FilePath, FileMode.Open);
            try
            {
                Aes aes = Aes.Create();
                byte[] iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];
                int numBytesToRead = aes.IV.Length;
                int numBytesRead = 0;
                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    int n = fileStream.Read(iv, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
                    if (n == 0) break;

                    numBytesRead += n;
                    numBytesToRead -= n;
                }
                byte[] key =
                {
                    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                    0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16
                };
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(fileStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                StreamReader decryptReader = new(cryptoStream);
                string decryptedMessage = await decryptReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                List<string> decryptedStringList = decryptedMessage.Split('\n').ToList();
                fileStream.Close();
                return decryptedStringList;
           //     Console.WriteLine($"The decrypted original message: {decryptedMessage}");
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You are writing the IV for every block of data you append. Then when decrypting you read all blocks but  just using the first IV. So you still have the data of the IV in the stream and that gets decrypted also and you see that. For me you are somewhat lucky that you just get garbage decryption for the IV still in there and that the Cryptostream not just bails out.

Comment: Then what should I do? Should I declare aes and iv as global variables? I am new to encryption.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need some more structure to your file, if you're going to have one file with multiple records and multiple IVs needed for decrypting them. How about, for simple starters, not appending, but instead writing a new file? Or how about decrypting the entire file, adding the new strings on and re-encrypting the entire thing and overwriting, that way you only ever have one IV and a growing payload